# Scroll PrimeFaces datatable horizontally?

Tags: primefaces, datatable

If I set the attribute "scrollable=true" in a PrimeFaces datatable it is scrollable vertically. But is it possible to scroll this table horizontally?

Comment: The PrimeFaces dataTable component in 2.2 supports only vertical scrolling. But why do you want a horizontal scrolling in the dataTable? Is your dataset not displaying within the contents of the component?

Comment: 3.0.M3 has horizontal scrolling as well.

Answer (score 4):

Primefaces supports horizontal scrolling on datatable. Just specify it like that:

```
<p:dataTable scrollable="true" scrollWidth="700">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (XY);
Panel;

```
<h:panelGroup id="tbl" style="width:100%;overflow:auto;">
```

data table;

```
<p:dataTable  paginatorPosition="top" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300" style="width:100%"   resizableColumns="true"  lazy="true"  >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`<p:dataTable resizableColumns="true" tableStyle="width:auto" >`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Using this breaks lot of other datatable features... ises it carefully